# Cisco switch Python script in Flask HTML output

Tags: python, flask, networking, cisco

I have a python script that SSH's (Netmiko) into a Cisco switch, runs an "show interface status" command and outputs it to the screen. When running script from the CLI the output looks normal on a line by line bases. If I put this same script into a Flask setup, I get the output but the problem is there is no line by line separation as in CLI. It's all crammed together. So my question is, is there a way to format Flask to output it as it does on the CLI but in HTML? Below is my code and the outputs from both CLI and Flask. Thank you in advance.

**my_flask_app.py file**

```
    from flask import Flask, request
from processing import do_calculation
 
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
 
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def adder_page():
    if request.method == "POST":
        number1 = request.form.get("number1")
        result = do_calculation(number1)
        return '''
                <html>
                    <body>
                      <p> {result} </p>
                    </body>
                </html>
        '''.format(result=result)
 
    return '''
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>Enter switch IP:</p>
                <form method="post" action=".">
                    <p><input type= "text" name="number1" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Check Status" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    '''
```

**Processing.py file**

```
   from netmiko import ConnectHandler
 
 
def do_calculation(number1):
    iosv_l2 = {'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'username': 'user1', 'password': 'password123', 'ip': number1}
 
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**iosv_l2)
    result = net_connect.send_command('show int status')
    return result
```

**Output from Flask - not desired**

> Port Name Status Vlan Duplex Speed Type Gi0/1 1st Flr AP notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/2 2nd Flr AP connected trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/3 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/4 ESXi Server connected 101 a-full a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/5 Ooma VoIP connected 101 a-full a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/6 Ring Alarm connected 101 a-full a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/7 1st Flr AP connected trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/8 Bench notconnect 101 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/9 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/10 Living Room TV connected 101 a-full a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/11 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/12 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/13 trunk to VM Server connected trunk a-full a-100 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/14 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/15 to lab-s1 connected trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/16 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/17 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/18 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/19 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/20 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/21 pfSense Trunk Re0 notconnect 1 auto auto 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/22 Office switch connected trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/23 to OPT1 (RE0) on F connected trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/24 to LAN (RE2) on FW connected 101 a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX Gi0/25 notconnect 1 auto auto Not Present Gi0/26 notconnect 1 auto auto Not Present Gi0/27 notconnect 1 auto auto Not Present Gi0/28 notconnect 1 auto auto Not Present

**Output from CLI - desired**

> Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
> Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
> Vlan101                192.168.1.2     YES manual up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/2     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/3     unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/4     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/5     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/6     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/7     unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/8     unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/9     unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/10    unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/11    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/12    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/13    unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/14    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/15    unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/16    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/17    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/18    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/19    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/20    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/21    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/22    unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/23    unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/24    unassigned      YES unset  up                    up
> GigabitEthernet0/25    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/26    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/27    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
> GigabitEthernet0/28    unassigned      YES unset  down                  down

Comment: Hi, perhaps put the text in a `<pre></pre>` tag, or replace each newline with a `<br>`

Comment: `HTML` doesn't respect new line `\n` but it needs `<br>` - or you have to put text in `<pre></pre>` or `<code></code>` and then it will respect new line `\n`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks @IronMan!  And you too furas!